# How to create a Kotlin DSL using kts files like Gradle

Tags: kotlin, dsl, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I am trying to make a configuration file much like Gradle build scripts, but I don't know how to evaluate a .kts file that uses a DSL

I have already tried using KotlinJsr223JvmLocalScriptEngineFactory, but that is very ugly when it comes to binding variables, and I have no idea if it can have the context set to something else for DSLs.

I have tried this:

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.script.jsr223.KotlinJsr223JvmLocalScriptEngineFactory

fun main() {
    val source = """
        println("Hi!")
        println(bindings["a"])
    """.trimIndent()
    val engine = KotlinJsr223JvmLocalScriptEngineFactory().scriptEngine
    engine.eval(source, engine.createBindings().apply {
        put("a", "b")
    })
}
```

but that doesn't support many things such as default imports, setting the `this` context (I'm not sure what it's really called) and nicely. I have tried following [making auto completion work in kotlin scripts](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/make-auto-completion-work-in-kotlin-scripts-with-context/10185/5) but it doesn't work.